# wxlua self changing value?

Tags: lua, wxwidgets, self, wxlua

I'm trying to draw some stuff using wxlua.

```
ExampleClass = {}

function ExampleClass:New(someWxPanel)
  local obj = {}
  setmetatable(obj, self)
  self.__index = self
  self.m_panel = someWxPanel
  return obj
end

function ExampleClass:OnPaint()
  local dc = wx.wxPaintDC(self.m_panel)
   --paint some stuff
end


local example = ExampleClass(somePanel)
somePanel:Connect(wx.wxEVT_PAINT, example.OnPaint)
```

I get the following error message:
wxLua: Unable to call an unknown method 'm_panels' on a 'wxPaintEvent' type.

While in any other function I define as Example:SomeFunction() self points to my Example instance and I can perfectly access its members here self is a wxPaintEvent?

How did this happen? Does the Connect somehow change self? How can I access my members now?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: setmetatable(obj, self) shoudl be correct. At least that's how I know it from other sources including the Lua reference.

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register `example.OnPaint` as the event handler in `somePanel:Connect(wx.wxEVT_PAINT, example.OnPaint)`, it always gets the event as the first parameter, but your method expects the object (`self`) passed as the first parameter, hence the error you get. You need to replace the registration with something like this:

```
somePanel:Connect(wx.wxEVT_PAINT, function(event) example:OnPaint(event) end)
```